# Using tags creatively

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

This question is about [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) but I believe it applies to tagging in general.

Is it appropriate to use tags to store little details about a user's activity, such as their interaction history?

For example: our user last wanted the demo panel closed, so we store this as a tag called `home_demo_closed`, which is then easily searchable on the next page load.

The alternative is adding a column to the database every time there's a new point of interaction we want to store. This seems like overkill to me - clunky, lots of work to implement, and too 'fixed' given how rapidly the front-end design can change.

What do you think is the best way to proceed with this - is there a design flaw with using tags for 'creative' purposes like this that I'm not considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Philosophically, it seems like a "tag" would be the wrong thing to use here - a tag is a way of indexing a data object with one or more searchable or categorizable terms. That having been said, the underlying technology (a many-to-many relationship with data objects on one side and atomic data elements on the other) is a perfectly viable approach. I'd probably go ahead and create a fresh table `preferences` and a join table `user_preference_settings`, just from a code readability perspective.

It's like the old joke about the physics student who was asked how he would learn the height of a building using a barometer. The answer he gave was "Drop the barometer off the top of the building, and time how long it takes to hit the ground." Clever, effective, but certainly not the answer someone else would expect to find. :)